How to allow other users to modify files uploaded to SFTP server (login as other user)
I have an SFTP server and I can send files to it as let's say user1. I have another user (user2) in that server and I want to be able to remove/modify files uploaded to the user1's configured sftp folder.
What I tried is to add user2 to the group of user1. Thus I can read files uploaded, but get "permission denied" on the removal of files as user2.
The output of ls -l a for files uploaded is: -rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1 400691 Jul  1 12:16 114.xlsx
The output of command groups user2 is user2: user2 user1
How do I allow user2 to delete these uploaded files?
UPDATE
I found out that the upload folder (let's say /data/uploads) belongs to user1, but group is root. That could be the reason why I cannot write (delete from) to that folder. Will changing the group to user1 help? Will this affect the SFTP server anyhow?

First define your permissions model.

add user2 to the group of user1

I don't know what your permissions model should be, but it should CERTAINLY not be this. There is a reason that a group is created for each user on Linux - this  should be exclusive except under some very rare edge cases.
For illustration purposes, I will create a new group containing the named users. The new group is called docusers:
# addgroup docusers
# usermod -G docusers user1
# usermod -G docusers user2

Next, you want files uploaded to writeable by the group. You are probably using openssh as your ssh/sftp server, in which case, you need to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config, find the line containing sftp-server and add  -u 002, e.g.
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -u 002

Then restart your ssh server (systemctl restart ssh-server).
Then you need to align the existing files and directories with the permission model:
# chown -R user1:docusers /data/uploads
# chmod -R g+rw /data/uploads
# find /data/uploads -type d -exec chmod g+x {} \;

Now you need a way to tell the system which group it should use for new files:
# find /data/uploads -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;

